# Phonegap iphone : camera plugin : orientation issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap in my application.

using camera plugin for capture and select image

I am facing orientation issue in different cases:

When allowEdit : true and iphone orientation is open, then it works fine

When allowEdit : true and iphone orientation is locked, then it work fine only when click photo in portrait orientation, in all other orientation image rotates

When allowEdit : false, then it work fine only when click photo in landscape left orientation, in all other orientation image rotates

Same issue with video too.

Comment: everything is working ... but main issue is that image rotates 90 degree, 180 degree, 270 degree according to orientation..

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't exactly understand what the issue is. Does this occur in the normal iOS photo capture mode? AFAIK you can't really control the behavior of that view, so I would guess that this isn't a bug but intended behavior?

Comment: I have mention 3 case in the post.......... 1. allowEdit : true and iphone orientation is open >>>>>>>>>>>>> 2. allowEdit : true and iphone orientation is locked >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 3. allowEdit : false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved for image
passing argument `correctOrientation: true` from phonegap

But still have issue in Video.. Video rotate to 90 degree angle

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the webViewDidFinishLoad function of `AppDelegate.m`.

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
```